# python : AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, attributes, polygon, geotiff

I am trying to extract the values associated to each pixel in a tiff image using the gdal library.

```
 # Create a polygon from the pixel coordinates
            polygon = Polygon([(x_min, y_min), (x_min, y_max), (x_max, y_max), (x_max, y_min)])

 # Associate the polygon with the value
            polygon.value = value
```

When I try to access the value of the polygon I got the error

`AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `Polygon`?

Comment: Please edit the question and put all relevant information into this instead of writing a new comment. But it is still unclear where this `value` attribute come from!?

Comment: I imported the polygon object from the shapely.geometry library. It is supposed to represent the shape of the field that I wnt to extract.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I discovered that the polygon object do not really have the value attribute ( it only have two attributes : 'exterior' which is the ring which bounds the positive space of the polygon and 'interiors' which is a sequence of rings which bound all existing holes.), so I decided to change the logic that I am working with.

```
polygon = Polygon([(x, y), (x+1, y), (x+1, y+1), (x, y+1)])
value = int(array[y, x])  # Convert pixel value to int
```

This code works perfectly well for my use case.